# How to arrange Array in Table Format in Html/Php

Tags: php, html, arr

How to print array data in table format with  appropriate table head and data. Or in DIV also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Array</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $arr = array
  (
  array("U Jadeja",100,100),
  array("A Dave",200,200),
  array("K Lathiya",300,300),
  array("A Kanani",400,400),
  array("Brock lesnar",400,400),
  );
?>

<


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Array</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $arr = array
  (
  array("Upendrasinh",100,100),
  array("Ankit dave",200,200),
  array("Krunal Lathiya",300,300),
  array("Arjun Kanani",400,400),
  );

  $arrCount = count($arr);


  // $arrsubcount = count($arr[0]);
  // echo $arrsubcount;
  // echo "<br>";

  $arraycell=count($arr[0][0]);
  $arraycell=$arraycell;

echo '<table border="5px" width="100%">';
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Name</th>";
            echo "<th>Score</th>";
            echo "<th>Score2</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
  for($arrayrow=0;$arrayrow<=$arrCount-1;$arrayrow++){
            echo "<tr>"."<td>".$arr[$arrayrow][0]. "</td>"; 
                for($arraycolumn=0;$arraycolumn<$arraycell;$arraycolumn++){
                    echo "<td>".$arr[$arrayrow][$arraycell]."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$arr[$arrayrow][$arraycell+1]."</td>"."</tr>";
                }
    }
  echo '</table>';

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you answered your own question?

Comment: but you answered moments after asking question .. looks like you were already ready with question and the answer.

Comment: @user5173426, Self answers are [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Do not berate a user for doing exactly what we ask them to do. The option to answer the question appears immediately under the "Post Question" button.

Comment: @Guanxi Please see the above comment, and understand that self answered questions are [encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)